# Android jetpack LazyColumnFor items?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

HI i am new to using jetpack compose and in my code below i am trying to fetch data from a http request(a list of movies) and then adding each movie to the LazyColumnFor list(which is like a recyclerView)

HOwever, the list i pass to the LazyColumn is not compatibe and i get the following error:

```
lazyColumnFor Required:List<TypeVariable(T)>Found:List<MovieItem>?
```

Below is my composable function

```
 @Composable
fun getTopMovies(){

    val topMovies by movieListViewModel.getTopMovies().observeAsState()

    LazyColumnFor(items = topMovies?.data?.results?)
}
```

THe API call i make using globalScope courotine

```
  val result = MutableLiveData<Resource<DATA>>()
    result.value = Resource.loading(null)

    GlobalScope.launch {
        try {

            val response = client.await()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val data = response.body() as DATA
                result.postValue(Resource.success(data))
            }


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            result.postValue(Resource.error(e.toString(), null))
        }
```

THe movie list i return is below:

```
data class MovieList(val page: Int,
                 @SerializedName("total_results") val totalResults: Int,
                 @SerializedName("total_pages") val totalPages: Int,
                 val results: List<MovieItem>)
```

Comment: You have a nullability problem. Rather than the trailing `?`, try `.orEmpty()`.